# Problemas rutas en produccion, Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, rutas

Escribo por que mi problema es el siguiente tengo un sitio básico hecho con `angular` a modo de practica pero caí en cuenta de dos cosas una vez que lo lleve a producción ( `ng build --prod` ), que en los lugares que deje el `href` y no el `routerLink` simplemente redirecciona pero me aparece el siguiente error,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y es básicamente lo mismo si intento acceder por medio de la `url` poniendo directamente **http://localhost/login** ( en este caso lo subí a un servidor local pero al subirlo a un hosting el error persiste )

¿Hay alguna forma que se pueda acceder a distintos componentes, no solo al principal por la url ? algo así como en el entorno de desarrollo que era solamente poner *http://localhost:4200/login*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probablemente este fallando en algo de la rutas o eso quiero pensar :D

```
<code>
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/main',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'media',
    component: MediaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListComponent
  }
  ,
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  }
  ,
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found'
  }  
];
</code>
```

Answer (score 4):

Se trata del problema habitual con el routing HTML5 y la configuración del servidor web. Al cargar el enlace directamente el servidor web intenta resolver la ruta y no Angular,
ya que Angular aún no se ha cargado debido a que el index del sitio no se ha cargado... (y por consiguiente ningún script se ha cargado en el navegador)

Respecto a este tema tienes dos opciones:

#### 1. Configurar la aplicación para realizar el routing con el hash.

En el módulo donde estás definiendo las rutas, al momento de proveer el `RouterModule`
especifica en las opciones que use el hash:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true })],
```

De esa manera, no habrá problema con el routing de HTML, sin embargo la URL de tu aplicación ahora se verá así:

http://localhost:4200/#/login

#### 2. Delegar esa configuración al servidor web.

Sea Nginx, Apache, ExpressJS, etc... debes configurarlo para que siempre redireccione primero al `index.html` antes de intentar resolver una ruta. 
Te dejo dos ejemplos:

**NodeJS**

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

**Nginx**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```